# Django pagination of filtered results using AJAX

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to figure this out for days and was unable to find any useful information online. 
What I am trying to do is paginate objects from my model after filtering them using a drop down menu and supplying the data to python via AJAX. I know where the problem is but I am not sure how to solve it. I have two templates, first one is:

**entry_index.html**:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<select class="selectpicker" name="times" onchange="FilterCategories()" id="times">
     <option value="1">last 24 hours</option>
     <option value="30">past month</option>
     <option value="365">past year</option>
     <option value="10000">all time</option>
 </select>
</form>

<ul id="all-games" class="list-unstyled">
{% include page_template %}
</ul>
```

The template that is being included in the above template is **entry_index_page.html**:

```
{% if objects %}
    {% for object in objects %}
     do something
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if objects.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ objects.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ objects.number }} of {{ objects.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if objects.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ objects.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^$', views.entry_index, name='index')
```

**views.py**:

```
def entry_index(
    request,
    template='entry_index.html',
    page_template='entry_index_page.html'):

    date_from = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)
    obj_list=Object.objects.filter(submitted__gte = date_from).order_by('-votes')
    message=[]
    context = {
    'objects': obj_list,
    'page_template': page_template}

    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template
        message = []

        if request.method == "GET":
            time_range = request.GET.get('time_range')
            if time_range is not None and time_range != u"":
                time_range = request.GET['time_range']
                date_from = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=int(time_range))
                obj_list= Object.objects.filter.filter(submitted__gte=date_from)

    paginator = Paginator(obj_list, 2)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        objects= paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        objects= paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        objects= paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context.update({"message":message,"objects":objects})

    return render_to_response(
    template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**ajax.js**:

```
function FilterCategories() {
    var timePosted = document.getElementById('times');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "",
        data: {
            'time_range': timePosted.value,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: filterResults,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}
```

Now to explain what I think is going on and hopefully someone can help me find a solution.

When the home page is loaded (entry_index.html) the model gets filtered based on the first option in the drop down menu (i.e. value="1", which is filtering for the data entries submitted within the last day). The obj_list variable gets populated and is passed to the paginator and everything works as expected. I get a certain number of pages and can navigate through pages. Now lets assume we are on the home page again and I select "all time" from the drop down menu. This will trigger the onchange callback and it will call the FilterCategories() function. Note the url in AJAX is "" (an empty string, so pointing to my index page). According to urls.py, it will call my entry_index() view. Because request is ajax, the template used will change (page_template becomes the new template, page_template = entry_index_page.html). Because the new time range specified with the drop down menu and passed on with ajax, I get a new obj_list which is then paginated and produces "objects" which are then passed as context onto the template. Up until this point everything works as expected. I get right amount of pages etc. However, the problem starts when I try to go to the next page with the newly selected filter. When I click the next page button, the request that is being made is not an ajax request so everything that is in the request.is_ajax() conditional is not executed. So in another words a click to the next page is calling my entry_index view again and the template being used this time around is entry_index.html and my filter is reset back to the default, which is the "last 24 hours" filter. Therefore, when I click the next page what I end up getting is actually the default home page again instead of getting the next page of objects with my newly selected drop down filter.

My question is, is there an easy way to fix this so that I can scroll through the pages of my filtered model? Or should I completely abandon this approach and there is an easier way to do this? I apologize for a long post and I hope someone out there will be able to help me out. Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: I'm not entirely following your process, but you might find it easier to use a single template, and just use AJAX to replace data or chunks of HTML on the page itself, rather than doing new page loads. It would be faster and would have fewer moving parts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of an approach I've taken to having dynamic content displayed on a page using Django and Ajax:

I was tooling a little browser Sci-fi game just to practice this specific technique. Everything took place in a single view:

```
class GameViewport(TemplateView):
    template_name = "game_viewport.html"

    @cached_property
    def slug(self):
        return self.kwargs['slug']

    @cached_property
    def game(self):
        return Game.objects.get(url=self.kwargs['slug'])

    @cached_property
    def player(self):
        return Player.objects.get(game=self.game)

    @cached_property
    def current_planet(self):
        return self.player.current_planet

    @cached_property
    def left_column(self):
        player = self.player

        if player.current_location:
            node = player.current_node
            if len(Location.objects.filter(node=node)) == 0:
                spawn_locations(node)
                locations = Location.objects.filter(node=node)
            else:
                locations = Location.objects.filter(planet=node)
            html = "Other Sites in ".format(str(node))
            for location in locations:
                html += '<li><a href="" class="locationChoice"></a>{} ({})</li>'.format(location.name, location.type.name)
            return html

        elif player.current_node:
            planet = player.current_planet
            if len(Node.objects.filter(planet=planet)) == 0:
                spawn_nodes(planet, get_name_choices())
                nodes = Node.objects.filter(planet=planet)
            else:
                nodes = Node.objects.filter(planet=planet)
            html = '<h4><b>Other Starports on {}:</b></h4>'.format(planet.name)
            for node in nodes:
                html += '<li><a href="" class="nodeChoice"> {} </a> ({})</li>'.format(node.name, node.type.name)
            return html

        elif player.current_planet:
            system = player.current_system
            html = '<h4><b>Known Planets in {}:</b></h4>'.format(system.name)
            for known_planet in player.known_planets.filter(solar_system=system):
                html += '<li><a href="" class="planetChoice"> {} </a> ({})</li>'.format(
                    known_planet.name,
                    known_planet.classification.name
                )
            return html
        else:
            html = '<h4><bShip Status</b></h4>'
            html += '<p><b>Fuel:</b> 100%</p>'
            return html
```

So as you can see, the left column would generate different html data based on what the player's current settings are. This would be plugged into the template like so:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="leftColumn">
        {% autoescape off %}
          {{ view.left_column }}
        {% endautoescape %}
    </div>
</div>
<a href="{% url "visit_planet" view.slug %}" id="visitPlanet"></a>
```

If the user clicked on a new location, I would send her decision through AJAX:

```
$(".planetChoice").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var submission_data = {planet: $(this).text()};
    console.log(submission_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#visitPlanet').attr('href'),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data: submission_data,
        success: function(html_data) {
                window.location.reload();
        },
        failure: function(data) {
            alert('Something went wrong. Please refresh the page.');
        }
    });
});
```

All this would do is update the player's state and reload the page according to her new settings:

```
def visit_planet(request, slug):
    player = Game.objects.get(url=slug).player_1
    planet = Planet.objects.get(name=request.GET.get('planet', "").strip())

    if planet:
        player.current_location = None
        player.current_node = None
        player.current_planet = planet
        player.save()

    response = {'status': 1, 'message': "Ok"}

    return JsonResponse(response)
```

Thus displaying the new data, as determined by the `left_column` property.

I went about this by changing the state in the database, but it could just as easily be accomplished with session variables. I found it to be a relatively clean and DRY way of cycling dynamic content. It also has the advantage of giving Django an opportunity to generate or modify data in between clicks.

Not sure if this applies to your situation, but hopefully it sparks an idea!

EDIT: You don't even necessarily need to output HTML. Here's an approach I am using in a different application:

```
<!--Product Tile #1-->
{% if view.tile_data.0 %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card hoverable">
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-block" id="tile_{{ view.tile_data.0.invoice }}_id">
            <!--Title-->
            <h4 class="card-title">Shipment {{ view.tile_data.0.invoice }}</h4>
            <!--Text-->
            <p class="card-text">{{ view.tile_data.0.supplier.name }}
            <br>
            <b>{{ view.tile_data.0.lbs|floatformat }} Lbs @ {{ view.tile_data.0.price }} USD</b>
            <br>
            {{ view.tile_data.0.variety.commodity }} {{ view.tile_data.0.variety }} {{ view.tile_data.0.inshell|shell_display }}</p>
        </div>
        <!--/.Card content-->
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
<!--./Product Tile #1-->
```

This data is directly fed through the view from a model manager:

```
def tile_data(self, status, first, last):
    return self.model.objects.filter(status=status)[first:last]
```